# Moderator re-tag requests: [characters] and [character-naming]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

- [characters](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) should excised in favor of [character](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character); I'd be in favor of cutting the plural tag out completely.
- I think [character-naming](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-naming) should be synonymed to [naming](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"character-naming" has been merged into "naming".
"character" has been merged into "characters"

Answer (score 3):

I can distinguish "character creation" (how does he look, behave, ...) from "character-development" (how does he react to the conflicts, change his attitudes, ...), but I can't when compared to "character".

You can use "character" for both, creation and development, and separating them does not sound like a feasible idea. You probably first create them, before they develop, but a separate consideration doesn't make sense.

Keep "character", kick the other.

Comment: Possibly I should be asking for a merge, rather than a synonym?

Comment: @Standback: Is there a difference? I have to admit, I'm not up-to-date what can be done with tags (merge, synonymize, whatever).

Comment: Me neither :P Hence the last comment. "Tag synonym" kind of implies that both the tags mean the same thing, and can be used interchangeably. But you're saying, quite correctly, that that's not _quite_ what we want here.

Comment: "Merge" means "take everything under X and retag it to Y, optionally making X a synonym of Y" while creating a synonym merely makes X mean Y -- if things already have tag X then a merge is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The SE standard (at least SOFU) discourages the use of singular tags. So [characters](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) would win. Why do you like the singular version better?

[naming](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) could also mean other things, like the title of the book. I would get rid of [naming](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming), because it's too imprecise.

Comment: Re: character - Because "character" covers "That guy sure has a lot of character!" and "I'm developing my protagonist's personality and character."  Whereas "characters," at least to my knowledge, implies something  more on the line of "cast members." But maybe that's just my own association?

Comment: Re: naming, that's precisely my point - [naming] covers [character-naming] and other types of naming as well. Different [naming] tags for characters, locations, novels, stories, races, etc etc etc sounds superfluous to me; my own opinion is that a single [naming] tag would cover those all nicely.

Comment: @Standback: One [naming] tag for all? Hmm, does not sound that bad. I understand now your preference for singular [character], but I'm unsure if this exception of the "plural rule" is really needed.

Comment: I HEREBY CALL UPON THE ALLMIGHTY COMMUNITY TO EXPRESS THEIR OPINION ON THE MATTER! ...or, we could just make it a tag synonym :P

Comment: Maybe the almighty community just consists of two people, @Standback.

Comment: Always a possibility. More almightiness to go around!